# PrimeFaces Chart Interactive Mode - Displaying Extra bean Info In Growl Box

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 4 as http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/interactiveCharts.jsf, there are 2 methods which returns (growl) the **Item** and **Serie** indexes as we click on a corresponding bar in the chart.

I want to display some extra entity bean information (like name, value, gender etc) in the growl box. Ho can I do it?

This is the (main) code of the managed bean (see the last method):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ChartBean {

public ChartBean() {
}

private final Map<Integer, Map<String, Number>> HorasRealizadasPorFunci = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<Integer, Map<String, Number>> HorasOrcadasPorFunci = new HashMap<>();
private CartesianChartModel cartesianChartModel;

@EJB
private OrcFacade of;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
//see code through link above
}

private void createCartesianChartModel() {
//see code through link above
}

private void addOrUpdateRlz(Integer matricula, String funci, Number horas) {
//see code through link above
}

private void addOrUpdateOrc(Integer matricula, String funci, Number horas) {
//see code through link above
}

private void populateMap(Map<Object, Number> map, Map<String, Number> data) {
//see code through link above
}

public CartesianChartModel getCartesianChartModel() {
//see code through link above
}

public void setCartesianChartModel(CartesianChartModel cartesianChartModel) {
//see code through link above
}

public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {
    /* Primefaces simple example:
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item selected",
    "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);*/

    //implement code to get bean info here
}

}
```

This is the partial JSF which renders the chart:

```
<p:barChart id="barStacked" value="#{chartBean.cartesianChartModel}">
   <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{chartBean.itemSelect}" update="msg" />
</p:barChart>
<p:growl id="msg" />
```

For more details about the code, please visit [PrimeFaces Chart From Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660371/primefaces-chart-from-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try getting the CartesianChartModel Component from the ItemSelectEvent object?

```
Integer seriesIndex = event.getSeriesIndex();

CartesianChartModel cModel = (CartesianChartModel((org.primefaces.component.chart.Chart)event.getSource()).getModel();
```

Then you do something like this:

```
List Map<String, Number> cData= cModel.getData().get(seriesIndex);
```

From there you can find the ChartSeries object using event.getItemIndex(). The javadoc for ChartSeries has some getters for all the properties you're looking for.

mbeddedsoft.