# Correctly displaying and using Primefaces bar chart from database

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, charts

I'm having a hard time understanding how to display PF charts from the database. The PF user documentation mostly covers examples of how to statically produce charts (ie: by hard coding values). On this site, I've only seen a few questions here about how to produce PF charts from database. I found this question helpful:

[PrimeFaces Chart From Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660371/primefaces-chart-from-database)

But it doesn't really explain the logic and the methods needed to correctly implement PF charts from DB. I tried the following example myself. The view is:

```
<p:panel>
<p:barChart value="#{rigtestBean.cartChart}"/>
</p:panel>
```

The managed bean method:

```
public CartesianChartModel createRigTestModel() {
    cartChart = new CartesianChartModel();
    ChartSeries rigs = new ChartSeries();
    List<Rigtest> rList = rigFacade.findAll();
    Map<Object, Number> rigMap = new HashMap<>();        
    for(Rigtest o: rList) {

        rigMap.put(o.getCountry().getCountryname(), o.getRignum());

        rigs.setData(rigMap) ;
        cartChart.addSeries(rigs);

    }
    return cartChart;

}
```

The above interacts with a table called RigTest which has the following values (country name, number of rigs, date):

Country name: USA, USA, France, France
Rig numbers: 2, 20, 40, 200

When running the code, only two data points are picked up in the resulting graph. These are 2 and 200 and the rest of the chart series seems to be ignored. The debugger shows that the map is being populated correctly and the Chart series ('rigs') is also populated correctly. This suggests that the problem is in the way I am adding the series to the CartesianChartrmodel instance ('cartChart'). Would really appreciate any advice on where I'm going wrong. On a wider issue, any advice of where I can read some material on implementing PF charts from CRUD operations using JPA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be the same for JSF-Primefaces to have values from the DB or static ones, as it takes them from the managed bean. So I guess your problem comes with JPA usage. First try to play with JPA and see if your test entities are properly populated. Once they're, it should be the same way for JSF using them or statically populated values.

Comment: Uhmmm.... you use a hashmap and your 'record set' just contains to distinct keys... No wonder you only have two points

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Xtreme. The console output from the JPA shows that the values are properly populated for the HashMap and the entire series is being fetched. This suggests that my mistake could be in how I'm adding the series to the model? I'll play wiith th JPA some more but so far the JPA looks like it's behaving correctly and the problem is in how the graph is actually being rendered by PF

Comment: Apologies Kuketjie but I really did not understand your comment at all. Obviously I'm using Hashmap if you read the code in my question. As far as the record set containing distinct keys, these are entity attributes from which I aim to render. You seem to see the mistake I am making so kindly explaqin it clearly. Thank you

Comment: Putting _"Country name: USA, USA, France, France; Rig numbers: 2, 20, 40, 200"_ as keys and values in a hashmap will result in just two entries, exactly as you describe

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me understand my mistake a lot better. I used the table primary keys instead of country names in the for loop and it is now returning 6 different values. My problem now is that the loop is repeated 36 times. I need to understand how better to write the method so it only loops once through each record. This is a purely JPA problem I think and you have answered my concrete problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kukeltje's comments helped me find the answer. In my original method, initialization of the CartesianChartModel happened at the beginning of the method. Since this create method is called by the bean getter method, initializing the model instance at the beginning of the create seems to have several looping effects, causing the enhanced for loop to treat each record in the map as a series. This means 6 records are looped 36 times, 7 records 49 time and so on.

Initializing the model instance AFTER the the for loop and population of the map seems to fix the problem and result in the right number of records in the bar chart.

```
public void createRigTestModel() {

    ChartSeries rigs = new ChartSeries();

    List<Rigtest> rList = rigFacade.findAll();

    Map<Object, Number> rigMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Rigtest o : rList) {

        rigMap.put(o.getRigtestid(), o.getRignum());

        cartChart = new CartesianChartModel();
        rigs.setData(rigMap);
        cartChart.addSeries(rigs);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a bar chart, for example, a chartseries could be a set of bars. So, you have to set the data for each bar inside the for..loop and after this loop add the chartseries to the model. 
You can add many series (set of bars) to the chartmodel.

The code could be:

```
public CartesianChartModel createRigTestModel() {
 cartChart = new CartesianChartModel();
 ChartSeries rigs = new ChartSeries();
 List<Rigtest> rList = rigFacade.findAll();

 for(Rigtest o: rList) {
    rigs.set(o.getCountry().getCountryname(), o.getRignum());       
 }
 cartChart.addSeries(rigs);

 return cartChart;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This does not really help as it is virtually identical to my code and incorrect in any case as the initialization at the beginning of the method will result in unnecessary looping as the answer below suggests. Besides, your comments are quite well documented by the PF documentation. Thanks for the input but this is general information and does not answer the question